# Retrieving a list from an NSArray

Tags: cocoa, list, nsarray, nspredicate

I want to set a list from the contents of an array without running a for loop.
I used the `appendEntities` method to achieve this.

```
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[[self tempList] makeArray] mutableCopy];
[mutArray filterUsingPredicate :aPredicate];//Setting a user defined predicate format here.
NSArray *newListArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutArray];

//After setting the predicate I want the array content to be present in the entityList.
ISTModelList  *entityList = [[ISTModelList alloc] init];
[entityList appendEntities:newListArray];
NSLog(@"entityList %@",entityList);
```

While I am trying to print the list getting the below error in debugger console.

```
 -[__NSCFDictionary setContextKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10aca9090
```

How can I get the list from the array avoiding loops?

Comment: Did you try directing adding mutable array in ISTmodel list??

Comment: @hussainShabbir Hi.. I tried appending the mutable array directly to the EntityList `[entityList appendEntities:mutArray];`, but it also does not seem to work.

Comment: you have to use loops only to get the list